# How to Enable Data Deduplication in Windows 8.1 client

Tags: windows-8.1, deduplication, powershell-3.0, dism

How can i enable Data Deduplication in Windows 8.1 x64 client.

http://weikingteh.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/how-to-enable-data-deduplication-in-windows-8/

The above link discusses the same for a Windows 8 client. However, I need to know how to identify the packages for a Win8.1 OS.

Comment: Are you quite sure you want de-duplication? It is not particularly effective in the vast majority of applications and I venture to suggest *especially* in the case where someone wants to use it on a Windows platform.

Comment: @deed02392 It's for personal use. I have a dual storage laptop. And I run VM's on it for testing. If I can create a tiered storage pool with deduplication enabled I could save space and improve performance at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mvpskill.com%2Fkb%2Finstall-data-deduplication-for-windows-8-1-rtm.html) - it's a translated page but there is a link for the 8.1 files. I haven't tried it yet.

P.S. [Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_2FPh7Zo8anSHc0eEI4aHJ3X00/edit?usp=sharing) is the link to the cab files

---

Summary of translated page:

1. Download Installer File Server Role / Data Deduplication
2. Check Windows Features to make sure File Server Role is not installed.
3. Open an administrator command line and run `Install.cmd` in download directory.
4. Read the errors (if any), press any button to close the installation.
5. Check Windows Features to see if File Server Role is now installed.
6. Deduplicate a drive from powershell.

   - Example: `Set-DedupVolume -volume D: -ExcludeFolder d:\documents;d:\Music`
   - Check status from powershell: `Update-DedupStatus -Volume d:`

Comment: Can you summarize the translated page, so that if the link goes dead, your answer is still useful?

Comment: @JohnBensin I made an edit doing just that, should be visible once it passes review.

Comment: @LyleBrown [Looks good to me](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/156485).

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't get it to work...

`DISM Package Manager: PID=4680 TID=2012  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x80073701) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
DISM Package Manager: PID=4680 TID=1608 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x80073701)
DISM Package Manager: PID=4680 TID=1608 Failed processing package changes - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChanges(hr:0x80073701)
DISM Package Manager: PID=4680 TID=1608 The package Microsoft-Windows-FileServer-Package is not applicable to the image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessPackageChange`

Comment: Although, I see "Data Deduplication" in the list of available features. But it's an independent feature; not nested under "file server". And it fails to install too.
`PID=5568 TID=6672 Parent features must be enabled before this feature can be enabled. "Dedup-Core" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange
PID=5568 TID=6672 One or more features could not be enabled. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange(hr:0x80070032)
PID=5568 TID=6672 Failed while processing command enable-feature. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x8007003)`

Answer (score -2):

I have found a GUI program to manage Data Deduplication for Windows.

Weblink is: http://www.orontesprojects.com/?page_id=371
 Direct download is: http://www.orontesprojects.com/dedup/datadedup.zip

They deliver a free license to register the program…